# Convert Number Values Into Time in formula field

Tags: formula-field

I have formula field-

```
Hours_Left__c=Budgeted_Hours__c - Billable_Hours__c
```

Where I get Number value like-

```
8.70(Hours_Left__c) = 10.00(Budgeted_Hours__c )-1:30(Billable_Hours__c)
```

Here I want 8:30 in my Hours_Left__c field?

All fields are numbers.
I would like to know how can I convert a number column into time format (hh:mm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need all of your input to be in the same domain. Here, you're working with input in two different domains, which I'll call `decimal` and `time`.

The `decimal` domain (I'll assume a precision/scale of 2) goes from 0.00 - 0.99 before rolling over to 1.00.

The `time` domain goes from 0.00 - 0.59 before rolling over to 1.00

Getting the fractional part of your Billable Hours can be done in a formula field by using `MOD(Billable_Hours__c, 1)`

From there, converting from the `time` domain to the `decimal` domain is as simple as multiplying by 10/6. This is fairly basic math (unit conversion), so I won't go over it in detail.

When you're done with your work in the `decimal` domain, you want to covert back to the `time` domain by multiplying by 6/10. You only want to do this for the fractional part though.

In the end, your formula should look something like this

```
FLOOR(
  (Budgeted_Hours__c - FLOOR(Billable_Hours__c) - (MOD(Billable_Hours__c, 1) * 10/6))
)
+ 
(
  MOD((Budgeted_Hours__c - FLOOR(Billable_Hours__c) - (MOD(Billable_Hours__c, 1) * 10/6)), 1) * 6/10
)
```

There really isn't a way to get around the duplication in the resulting formula here. This is probably a sign that you'd be better off doing this in Apex rather than a formula field...but there it is.

+edit:
If your compiled formula size is too large, then either one, or both, of your fields is/are a formula field itself. It doesn't take too much, when referencing formula fields in another formula field , to push yourself over the compiled size limit.

At that point, you'd have 2 options:

- Work on making your other formula fields more efficient
- Create a workflow rule to perform a field update, taking the value of `Billable_Hours__c` or `Budgeted_Hours__c`, and sticking them into new number fields (that you'd need to create), and using those new number fields in the formula in place of the old, formula fields

Again, I must stress that doing this through Apex is likely a much better solution. You should seriously consider this if it is an available option.

Comment: I got error:
 Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (6,157 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters

Comment: The compiled formula size for me in one of my Sandboxes comes to 1056, so either your Budgeted_Hours__c is a formula field, or your Billable_Hours__c is (or both). Like I said at the end of my answer, you're probably better off doing this in Apex. I'll update my answer with another suggestion in case Apex isn't an option for you.