# Calculate Integers as Time format

Tags: process-builder, formula, formula-field

I am developing a flow (process builder) to perform integer calculations, but in the Time format.
Due to a limitation in BMC Helix Remedyforce, I was unable to use a Time field in CMDB and therefore my option was to use integers.

The used formula below, has some problem and I'm not able to solve it.

```
    FLOOR(([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c - 
FLOOR([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c) - 
(MOD([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c, 1) * 10/6))
)
+ 
(
MOD(([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c - 
FLOOR([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c) - 
(MOD([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c, 1) * 10/6)), 1) * 6/10
)
```

In the first run, when the valur of BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c is 20.00 and [BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c is 0.30, the result is ok 19.30

When I run again for the second time, the first time is 19.30 and I will subtract another 0.30, this time the result is 18.48.

I can repeat the steps in a pen test, but I do not know how to correct the calc. I expected 19.00 instead of 18.48

[Similar Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94984/convert-number-values-into-time-in-formula-field/334291#334291)

Comment: In the _Similar Post_ you linked to, the first field was `decimal` and the second field was `time`.  I just want to verify that your `[BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c` field is `decimal` and your `[BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c` is `time`....?

Comment: Hi Moonpie, no. In my case, both are NUMBER (with 2 positions). I need to calc integers and show value as time

Comment: Thanks. That helps narrow things down. For further clarification, can you give some examples of data that is in each of these two fields, and exactly what it represents?  (e.g., "1.5 in `Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c` means 1 hour and 30 minutes", "22.30 in `Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c` means it is 10:30pm", "22.50 in both fields means it is 10:30pm")

Comment: Hi Moonpie. I would that 1:30 min can be write as 1.30 and not 1,50 it will be easier to the staff analyst.

For example:

A supplier of my client bought 30 hours to be able to use as it wants. So, in the field **Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c**  (contracted hours) I will put 30.00

On the other hand, when a support analyst opens a ticket for this supplier, he will specify how many hours will be spent in the service (using field **Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c**), in my test I put 30 min (0.30).

Comment: This is what I am trying to determine: what data would be in those fields and what would it represent?  Please give some examples.

Comment: Both fields are number and those are represented as time.
Supplier always will buy full hours, for example 50 hours (or 50.00)

On the other side, the staff has a field (number, too) that will type 0:30 or 1:30 or 20:00 always the ammount of hours that will be spend.The staff always type HH:00 or HH:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Derek F*'s answer to the [Similar Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94984/convert-number-values-into-time-in-formula-field/334291#334291) you included in your question, the two fields were being used differently: one field for entering "2.5" to mean "two and one-half hours" (what *Derek F* called `decimal`), and the other field for entering "2:30" to mean "two and one-half hours" (what *Derek F* called `time`).

Since you indicated in your comment answers to my comment questions that both of your fields are being used the same way (which *Derek F* is referring to as `time`), then **you need to do your `* 10/6` conversion on both fields** in order to do your `decimal` calculations before you convert the final answer back to `time`.

*(Your first test worked because "20.00" has no fractions of an hour, and ".00" is the same in both `decimal` and `time` domains.  Then in your second test, you started with "19.30" which your formula used as a `decimal` [19.3] instead of converting it from 19.3 `time` to 19.5 `decimal`.)*

You *could* try this**...

```
FLOOR(( >> (FLOOR(
             [BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c
          ) + 
          (
             MOD(
                [BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c, 1
             ) * 10/6
          )
        ) << - 
FLOOR([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c) - 
(MOD([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c, 1) * 10/6))
)
+ 
(
MOD(( >> (FLOOR(
             [BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c
          ) + 
          (
             MOD(
                [BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c, 1
             ) * 10/6
          )
        ) << - 
FLOOR([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c) - 
(MOD([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c, 1) * 10/6)), 1) * 6/10
)
```

...**BUT**, to again quote *Derek F*:

> you'd be better off doing this in Apex rather than a formula field

---

** *I replaced your `[BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c` with what is between the ">>" and "<<". So if you use this, remove the ">>" and "<<".*

*Also note that I have NOT tested this.*

Comment: Hi, Moonpie, thank you a lot. I understood you mention. Your code works better than mine, but when I have 17.30 and subtract 0.30 its decrease 1.30 So, if the supplier has 17:30 hours and I use 0.30, the results is 16.

Comment: @Barcat : Oops. In order to start with the full remaining contracted hours in `Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c`, the converted fractional part should be **added** to the whole number of hours. So I edited my answer and changed the `-` to a `+` within both ">>" and "<<" sections that I originally added. For your example of 17.30, it should now start the calculation with _17.5_.  (The way I originally had it, it would have started with _16.5_.)  DISCLAIMER: I still haven't tested this myself.

Comment: And I am again going to quote _Derek F_ from his answer: "Again, I must stress that doing this through Apex is likely a much better solution. You should seriously consider this if it is an available option."

Comment: I will talk to the customer to understand If I can use apex on their side. Thank a lot, bro!

Comment: @Barcat : Did my correction make your formula work?  If not, please tell me what does not work so that I can attempt to correct my answer.  If so, please accept my answer as the correct one to the question you presented - even if your customer (hopefully) will allow you use Apex instead of this formula. :)

Comment: Hi, Moonpie, yes. The code worked on process builder, but sometimes we get an error to many SQL. It is natural, and after that the customer allow me to change it to apex. Do you know where can I find some documentation with exercises to calculate and convert data on apex?