# Subtraction between integers in the HH: MM format

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 4 fields on my incident form
**BH Estimativa** = String (filled in as HH: MM)
**BH Franquia** = Hours purchased by the customer to be used at any time
**BH Resultado** = is the conversion of the string field to number
**BH Franquia Restante Calculada** = Field with the difference between BH Franquia and BH Resultado

[image]

Initially I made the flow of this process in Process Builder, but due to the size of the process it is giving a lot of error, many times it is not able to complete the process and, therefore, I am putting it in the apex.

My doubt now is: in the apex it is possible to have a better solution than doing a lot of FLOOR and MOD, as I had done in Process Builder to perform the correct calculation (as shown in the image)
50.00 - 3.30 = 46:30

and not

50.00 - 3.30 = 46:70

I the next, I will present what I have until now on apex and the formula wrote on process builder.

Apex:

```
String BH_Est = BMC_inc.BH_Estimativa__c;              
          Decimal BH_Franquia = BMC_inc.BH_Franquia__c;
            
          BH_Est = BH_Est.replace(':', '.');
            
          Decimal BH_Est_Dec = decimal.valueOf(BH_Est);
          
          BMC_inc.BH_Resultado__c = BH_Est_Dec;
          BMC_inc.Franquia_Restante_Calculada__c =  (BH_Franquia - BH_Est_Dec);
```

Process Builder:

```
(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_Banco_de_Horas__c, ":", ""))/100)
 FLOOR((  (FLOOR(
         [BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c
      ) + 
      (
         MOD(
            [BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c, 1
         ) * 10/6
      )
    )  - 
 FLOOR([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c) - 
 (MOD([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c, 1) * 10/6))
 )
 + 
 (
 MOD((  (FLOOR(
         [BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c
      ) + 
      (
         MOD(
            [BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__r.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c, 1
         ) * 10/6
      )
    )  - 
 FLOOR([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c) - 
 (MOD([BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c].Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c, 1) * 10/6)), 1) * 6/10
 )
```

Comment: For others: In this case, an important detail was that `BH_Franquia` was a hybrid representation. It's captured as a decimal, but the fractional part's range is still in the time domain (0.00 - 0.59). My answer didn't capture this, but the underlying principle of _convert things from the time domain to the decimal domain_ is still applicable (it just needs to be applied to an extra variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the same general process that I laid out in [an answer of mine on another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94984/convert-number-values-into-time-in-formula-field/334291) applies pretty well here too.

In short, it'll make your life a whole lot easier if you convert things from the "time domain" (where minutes are mod 60) into the "decimal domain" before you attempt your calculation, and then convert back to the "time domain" to display the result (if needed or desired).

In other words, turn a time domain value of "3:30" into the decimal domain value of "3.50", then do your calculation.

```java
String BH_Est = BMC_inc.BH_Estimativa__c; // currently in the time domain
Decimal BH_Franquia = BMC_inc.BH_Franquia__c; //already in the decimal domain

List<String> BH_Est_parts = BH_Est.split(':');
Decimal BH_Est_Decimal = Decimal.valueOf(BH_Est_parts[0]) + (Decimal.valueOf(BH_Est_parts[1]) / 60.0);

BMC_inc.Franquia_Restante_Calculada__c = BH_Franquia - BH_Est_Decimal;

// Converting the result to the time domain
Integer hours = BMC_inc.Franquia_Restante_Calculada__c.intValue();
Decimal minutes = (BMC_inc.Franquia_Restante_Calculada__c - hours) * 60;
String remainingTime = hours + ':' + minutes.round(System.RoundingMode.UP);
```

As a class/method

```java
public class MyTime{
    // Represented in the decimal domain
    public Decimal timeRemaining;
    
    public void subtract(String timeSpent){
        // Convert the string from the time domain into the decimal domain
        //   to make calculating easy
        List<String> timeSpentParts = timeSpent.split(':');
        Decimal timeSpentDecimal = Decimal.valueOf(timeSpentParts [0]) + 
(Decimal.valueOf(timeSpentParts [1]) / 60.0);

        timeRemaining = timeRemaining - timeSpentDecimal;
    }

    public String formatRemaining(){
        Integer hours = timeRemaining .intValue();
        Decimal minutes = (timeRemaining - hours) * 60;
        
        return hours + ':' + minutes.round(System.RoundingMode.UP);
    }
}

MyTime mt = new MyTime();
mt.timeRemaining = 70.00;

mt.subtract('0:45');
system.debug(mt.timeRemaining); // Should output 69.25
system.debug(mt.formatRemaining()); // Should output 69:15

mt.subtract('0:45');
system.debug(mt.timeRemaining); // Should output 68.50
system.debug(mt.formatRemaining()); // Should output 68:30
```

Comment: Hi Derek, tks! I understood what you means, but when I try to run it I geeting an error: Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: List<String> String.split(String). Found nothing about it.

Comment: @Barcat That was a small mistake on my part. There are some methods in the String class that are static like join(), which would be called like `String.join(<list>,<seperator)`, but `.split()` is not one of them. I've edited my answer to make it (hopefully) correct.

Comment: Derek, thank you very much. I just didn't understand one thing. I did a test now where I had a value of 70.00 (in the decimal field) and set 0:30 (in the string field). The first time, it calculated correctly, it was 69.30. But the second time I run, the subtraction 69.30 - 0:30 had 68.48 I did not understand.

Comment: @Barcat I can't figure out what could cause that exact result based on your description, but it sounds like you're managing to convert something twice (like you have `0:30` in the time domain, convert that to `0.5` in the decimal domain, and then try to convert that _again_ into the decimal domain, resuing in something like `0.83`)

Comment: Here, Decimal minutes = (BMC_inc.Franquia_Restante_Calculada__c - hours)*60; If I delete *60 the result is 0.83 but even I leave it without the *60 the final result is not ok. I tried with your raw code, and when I run the second time the result is the same. So 29,30 (decimal field) - 0:30 (string field) > convertions and the result is 28:48. The integer is not ok and the minutos also.

Comment: @Barcat I'm not seeing the issue when I run this code in the developer console. If you're seeing `0,83`, the only way I can generate that number is by converting `0:30` => `0,5`, and then converting again from `0,5` => `0,83`. There must be an issue in your implementation where you're testing this being run twice causing `BH_Estimativa__c` to be converted twice.

Comment: Can I share my code? Sorry, but I not found the issue

Comment: Try to use on your side mt.timeRemaining = 69.30(decimal); and substract 0:30 (string)

Comment: @Barcat I've created a chat room for us: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/121144/time-conversion?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_time.htm) class, that's what it's made for.

```
public static Time timeDiff(Time t1, Time t2) {
    return t1.addSeconds(-t2.second()).addMinutes(-t2.minute()).addHours(-t2.hour());
}
public static Time convertTime(Decimal d) {
  return Time.newInstance(d.intValue(), (d-d.intValue())*60), 0, 0);
}
public static Time convertTime(String s) {
    String[] parts = s.split('\\D');
    return Time.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(parts[0]), Integer.valueOf(parts[1]), 0, 0);
}
```

Using these two methods, you can easily determine how much time is left:

```
Time timeRemaining = timeDiff(
  convertTime(BMC_inc.BH_Franquia__c), // Assuming .5 is 30 minutes
  convertTime(BMC_inc.BH_Estimativa__c));
```

The output is a Time value, which you can then convert to hours:minutes or hours.fractional, whichever you prefer, by using the hour() and minute() methods from timeRemaining:

```
String timeRemainingAsString = timeRemaining.hour() + ':' +
  (('0'+timeRemaining.minute()).right(2));
Decimal timeRemainingAsDecimal = timeRemaining.hour() + (timeRemaining.minute()/60.0);
```